# Geonodes Question: Is there a way to extrude the endpoint of a mesh line or curve in the tangent direction?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

For example if I have a curve or mesh line with many points in a shape of a snaker and I want it to extrude the end point along the same direction as the last edge.

I saw that there is a curve tangent node but I can't get it to work with the extrude mesh node.

Comment: a sketch or picture would be great so it is clear what u want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend the endpoints of a curve along their tangents in the following way:

[image]

Here I first capture the endpoints and their tangents in the point domain. Then I convert this curve into a mesh and extrude the selected vertices along the previously captured tangents. I scale the tangent of the first point with $-1$ so that it points in the opposite direction.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

---

And as an alternative you can also capture the values directly in the points of the curve, if the selection via the index does not work (for example, if you process several curves at the same time):

[image]